# Best datatype to store a java object to Oracle database

Tags: java, oracle, object, types, oracle12c

I want to save a java object (say a Person object) into a column in a table in Oracle 12c database. What is the best datatype suitable for this?

Comment: An idea could be create a person table, where each field of person object map to a column.

Comment: Thanks @Mritunjay. My class contains many attributes, if there is some datatype which won't take up much space I prefer saving entire object as a single entity

Answer (score 1):

You can store complex objects in Oracle in an XMLType or JSON format.

However it is probably the wrong tool for that job. If you are going to always access an object via a key, go for a dedicated Key-Value database product rather than an RDBMS. If you need to access objects via attributes, such as the person's name, then having that attribute buried in an object will be painful.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Myers. I decided to go as per your suggestion. ie not to bury attribute in an object and save each and every attribute in database columns

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement is a single field in an Oracle database table, I'd suggest a CLOB (assuming it's only ascii and no binary data). When storing binary data, use a BLOB.
BLOB= Binary Large OBject
CLOB = Character Large OBject.

Comment: Thanks for the info @Non Plus Ultra